# Travel maximum cities in given time limit

Tags: java, algorithm

There are `N` cities represented as vertices from 1 to N

We can travel from one city to another in a given time. This is represented by edges as arrays `U` and `V` where `(U[i], V[i])` represent an edge and time required to travel this edge is represented by `T[i]`

Now I should always start the travel from `1` and end at `N` in a given limited time `TimeLimit`, and cover the maximum number of cities from 1 to N.

Print the number of cities covered and the corresponding vertices in the order we can visit the cities.

**Example 1:**

```
N = 3, TimeLimit = 15
U = [1,2]
V = [3,3]
T = [9, 7]
```

**Output:**

```
2
1 3
```

**Explanation:**

```
we can start from 1 and reach 3 in time 9 which is less than the allowed time limit of 15

So cities are 1, 3 and so the number of cities is 2
```

**Example 2:**

```
N = 5, TimeLimit = 6
U = [1,3,1,2,4]
V = [3,5,2,4,5]
T = [3,3,2,3,2]
```

**Output:**

```
3
1 3 5
```

**Explanation:**

```
we can start from 1 and reach 3 in time 3 in time 3
we can continue to travel from city 3 to city 5 in time 3. So the total time is 3+3 = 6, so our time limit is 6. So valid path

So the cities covered are 1,3,5 and so the number of cities is 3.
```

What is the correct approach to solve this program?

**Update:**

I want to travel from the source city `1` to the destination city `N`. We have different paths to travel that take some time while traveling we will connect to other cities in between. The question is the maximum number of cities we can cover during this travel with a limitation that I need to reach the destination at the specified time limit. Hope this helps. If it is still not clear, please let me know so I will add more details.

Comment: _"I tried this way, but it's not the right approach."_ - why is it not the right approach? What problems do you see?

Comment: Is there a link to a page with this problem?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer, I don't have a link. Just curious to know, I see your comments for all my posts, are you a Robo in stackoverflow?

Comment: This looks like a bunch of random statements not remotely connected to the problem in question.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, The question is to travel from the source city `1` to the destination city `N`. We have different paths to travel that take some time while traveling we will connect to other cities in between. The question is the maximum number of cities we can cover during this travel with a limitation that I need to reach the destination at the specified time limit. Hope this helps. If it is still not clear, please let me know so I will add more details.

Comment: I understood the problem the first time around. This cannot be said about your code. It looks completely random. Why do you think it should work, or come close to working?

Comment: Can you reduce your problem down. One of the "test case"s that you fail? You haven't shown what the test cases are. What is the goal of your first loop? It looks like you're trying to find the shortest time to a node at U, but  it isn't going to accomplish that.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, yes I agree that my code is not correct, I want to know what approach is used to solve this kind of problem. I am deleting the code to avoid confusion.

Comment: @matt, it is failing the second example posted in my question. I deleted the code as my approach is not correct.

Comment: The comments aren't intended for you to remove your example. We want you to explain your code a bit. It will help you learn and maybe somebody can explain what you're doing wrong.

Comment: This is a slight variation of the TSP, there are no good methods of solving it. You can try an exhaustive depth first search with backtracking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common path finding routine. You could perform this by using a 'depth first search' which means we'll take every path and go all the way to the end, or until it exceeds time.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Pathfinder{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int goal = 5;
        int timeLimit = 6;
        int[] U = {1,3,1,2,4};
        int[] V = {3,5,2,4,5};
        int[] T = {3,3,2,3,2};

        int edges = U.length;
        List<int[]> path = new ArrayList<>();

        //node, search, time
        int[] link = { 1, -1, 0};
        path.add(link);
        List<int[]> valid = new ArrayList<>();

        while(path.size() > 0){
            int[] last = path.get(path.size() - 1);
            int[] next = null;
            for(int o = last[1] + 1; o<edges; o++){
                if(U[o] == last[0]){
                    int time = T[0];
                    if( time + last[2] <= timeLimit ){
                        //valid step.
                        next = new int[]{ V[o], -1, last[2] + time};
                        //keep track of what we searched
                        last[1] = o;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(next == null){
                //we've exhausted this path
                path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            } else{
                if( next[0] == goal ){
                    //we found our goal!
                    int[] cities = new int[path.size() + 1];
                    for(int j = 0; j<path.size(); j++){
                        cities[j] = path.get(j)[0];
                    }
                    cities[path.size()] = goal;
                    valid.add(cities);
                    //this is the end, so don't add next to the path.
                } else{
                    path.add(next);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int[] cs: valid){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cs));
        }
    }

}
```

When that code finishes, all of the paths that start at 1 and end at the goal will be in the array list `cities`.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: I am trying to understand this code. `List<int[]> path = new ArrayList<>()`, so path is empty list, then the code uses while loop on the empty list.  so how this code works?

Comment: Thank you, `This is a pretty common path finding routine` DFS is one approach, do we have other approaches also to solve the path find routine problems?

Comment: @technotigr You can implement this technique differently (often done recursively). That aside the "opposite" of depth first search is a breadth first search. Then you have the middle ground, such as "A*", where you choose which path you "open" based on a heuristic.

Comment: @technotigr in this particular problem you need to enumerate all the paths (or nearly all---those that take more than the time limit can be pruned early). DFS with backtracking fits this requirement nicely, but BFS or A* don't, or not easily at any rate. These algorithms work better than DFS when e.g. searching for the shortest path, but not in this case,